# How does Constraints.modifiesUtxoSet work?

Tags: plutus

I'm trying to understand how `Constraints.modifiesUtxoSet` works.
Can anyone give an example?

```
modifiesUtxoSet :: forall i o. TxConstraints i o -> Bool

Check whether every transaction that satisfies the constraints has to modify the UTXO set.
```

Answer (score 3):

The SimpleEscrow use case uses it:
https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-use-cases/html/src/Plutus.Contracts.SimpleEscrow.html#refundEp

Another example is the Crowdfunding use case:
https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-use-cases/html/src/Plutus.Contracts.Crowdfunding.html#contribute

Comment: I've seen them and after looking at the source of modifiesUtxoSet, I'd say that the purpose of modifiesUtxoSet is something like: "check if TxConstraints" does something"